# Mercurial: IntelliJ Idea: abort: cannot commit over an applied mq patch

Tags: intellij-idea, mercurial

I'm totally new with Mercurial.

When commiting and pushing my changes through IntelliJ Idea, I've accidently pushed the Commit and Create MQ patch button.

The commit went through, but push didn't. I force pushed my changes successfully (not a very good thing to do), but I cannot commit anything now.

I get this error:

```
1 file failed to commit: tip fix. abort: cannot commit over an applied mq patch
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fix was very simple:
I had to type these two commands in IntelliJ Idea terminal:

```
1. hg commit (with your message commit)
2. hg push
```

Now everything is back to normal.